# Opening a url browser from server using Java

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to open a browser window from a web server (using javascript) with a xml document sent via a xmlhttprequest response. The application uses javascript, so java 1.5 is no use here.
The code of the xmlhttp post is this:

```
String strSoap = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'      xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
"<soap:Body>" +
xml_body
"</soap:Body>" +
"</soap:Envelope>";    

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("SoapAction", some_action);
connection.setRequestProperty("Man", "POST url HTTP/1.1");
connection.setDoInput(true); 
connection.setDoOutput(true); 
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
java.io.DataOutputStream printout = new java.io.DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
printout.writeBytes(strSoap);
printout.flush();
printout.close();
java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Anothe posibility it will be to make the xmlhttprequest from the client side, which is the better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the xmlhttprequest from the client side. When you receive the response, open a new window (`window.open()`).

Using client-side JavaScript, you can then fetch the response from the original window and print it out in the new window.

For example, suppose the JavaScript variable `myXml` contained the text response to the xmlhttprequest in the original window then the executing `document.write(window.opener.myXml)` in the new window would write the response there.

Comment: Finally I used the request from the server, set the url from the reponse to the jsp form and after I used the window.open() from the onload of the page